# Writing a CV: how to handle a gap in employment because of studies?

Tags: resume, employment-gaps

My work and study history is a bit complicated:

- I was studying at uni while working part-time,
- then I quit the job and continued to study,
- I graduated and started working full-time,
- after a few years I quit the job and started another Bachelor degree full-time, without any job,
- after a few more years I graduated and started working again, taking Master degree at the same time.

I've heard that gaps are a big "no-no". How should I structure my CV to show that there are no gaps? All the CV formats I know of require separating work history from education. I don't think anyone reading the CV will bother checking that gaps in employment match the periods when I studied. How to show my work and study history to make the best impression? Should I make a graphical timeline that shows work and study periods on the same line?

Comment: I don't agree that the cited articles are duplicates; this business of gaps for study is not the same situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gaps are only a problem if there is no indication of what you were doing during that time. In fact you were either working or studying (or both) for all of the period. It's also true that hiring managers aren't that worried about gaps in a resume early in a career.

I would simply list the jobs you had, and their dates, and also the studies you did, with the dates. Anyone interested enough to analyse the dates will find that you were either working or studying for the whole period. Anyone who doesn't bother to analyse the dates probably isn't interested. Be prepared to give the chronological account you gave above if asked at an interview.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with DJClayworth. May I add the following points, first acknowledging that I don't know what you studied nor what jobs you did, so I'll speak very generally:

On the one hand, it may be an advantage to have such an interesting and apparently proactive employment+studies history. On the other hand, in your place, I would try to weave everything together in a neat storyline (e.g. in the cover letter or during an interview) to ensure that it doesn't look like I'm changing my mind all the time about what I want to do. Eg., if your first job is totally different to what you're looking for now, you may have taken it to save some money so that you could study again, or it helped you evolved this way or that and gave you ideas, etc. Of course, you know your history better, but I hope you're getting the general idea! I'm sure you can make it work!